# Correct Way of Handling A Corollary of A Corollary?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, proof

I have a conclusion S that is moderately interesting. While the corollary of S is more interesting, the corollary of the corollary of S is extremely interesting. Should I just label them corollary 1 and corollary 2 or is there a better way of handling that?

Comment: Labelling them 1 and 2 sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: You could name them "Jesse's Corollary" or something in case they become famous.

Answer (score 1):

It's a judgment call...  For example, if S is not really interesting by itself and there's a little work in going from S to its corollary, then it might make sense to call S a lemma and its corollary a theorem.  But it's perfectly fine to have two corollaries as well.  None of these options are technically incorrect, they're just signals to the reader about what role you think they play.